# “-gram” vs. “-graph”

Tags: etymology, suffixes

What’s the difference between the suffixes *-gram* and *-graph*? Is there any difference? Even if they are completely synonymous, what’s the difference in etymology?

For example, *pictograph* vs. *pictogram*, *cryptograph* vs. *cryptogram*, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These mean exactly the same thing, except when they don't. :)

From TheFreeDictionary.com

> **-gram**
>   *suff*.
>   1. Something written or drawn; a record: *cardiogram*.
>
> **-graph**
>   *suff*.
>   1. Something written or drawn: *monograph*.

This would seem to indicate that they are the same. And, in fact, if you look up **pictograph** and **pictogram** you see those words are synonyms. However, if you try to apply the logic to *all* words formed with the -gram/-graph suffix, you run into trouble:

> **ep·i·gram**  (p-grm)
>   *n*.
>   1. A short, witty poem expressing a single thought or observation.
>   2. A concise, clever, often paradoxical statement. See Synonyms at saying.
>   3. Epigrammatic discourse or expression.
>
> **ep·i·graph**  (p-grf)
>   *n*.
>   1. An inscription, as on a statue or building.
>   2. A motto or quotation, as at the beginning of a literary composition, setting forth a theme

So you really have to learn which is which on a case-by-case basis. Sorry.

BTW, the etymologies are different:

**-graph**[French -graphe, from Late Latin -graphus, from Greek -graphos, from graphein, to write; see gerbh- in Indo-European roots.]

**-gram** [Greek -gramma, from gramma, letter; see gerbh- in Indo-European roots. Sense 2, from telegram.]

Comment: The etymologies are different, but the etymological root is the same: **γράφω** (**gráphō**, “to scratch, to scrape, to graze”). https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%2Dgram#Etymology | https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%2Dgraph#Etymology

Answer (score 7):

This is a really interesting question. I hope a linguist jumps in with a solid answer, but here is what I can contribute.

If we look at Etymology Online, we can find [-graphy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-graphy&searchmode=none) as a suffix that means "to write or express by written characters."

Interestingly, if we look up [-gram](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-gram&searchmode=none), we find that it is a suffix from *telegram* that has been abstracted.  If we subsequently look up *[telegram](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=telegram&searchmode=none)*, we find out that it was coined with an erroneous formation of Greek.  The proper formation would have been *telegrapheme*.  So if we look up [-grapheme](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=grapheme&searchmode=none), we find that it is formed from -graph and [-eme](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-eme), or "unit."

Again I caution that I am not a linguist, but based on these etymologies, I'd suggest that -graph would refer to the content of the -gram, so a pictograph is what a pictogram contains.  It seems like there would be very few instances where one would distinguish between these meanings, so they could probably be used interchangeably.

Comment: Sometimes it's the other way around - a telegraph is what creates a telegram. So a pictograph should be a camera/printer that produces a pictogram.

Comment: Good point.  Maybe a -gram is a specific instance of a -graph?

Answer (score -1):

*-gram* refers to a picture or record while *-graphy* refers to the process of producing a picture or record.

Comment: This question is broader than just pictures and photography. It's talking about the suffixes in general.

Comment: It's also not about *-gram* and *-graph*, not *-gram* and *-graphy*.

Answer (score -3):

*-gram* and *-graph* mean the same thing: something written or recorded. An example for *-gram* is *diagram*, and an example for *-graph* is *geography*.

Comment: Are you saying anything that isn’t already covered by the other answers here?

Comment: This answer lacks substantiation in the form of facts, references, and specific expertise. Please edit to provide this supporting information. Also, note that if "-gram" and "-graph" mean the same thing the OP also asks what is the difference in etymology.